# Problem with redirection to PageNotFound in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is what the app-routing.module.ts looks like:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './shared/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', redirectTo: '/sign-in', pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I also have another routing module called auth-routing. It looks like that:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SignInComponent } from './components/sign-in/sign-in.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'sign-in', component: SignInComponent, pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AuthRoutingModule { }
```

I orginised the code like it's suggested in the tutorial and the problem I'm getting is whenever I navigate to the root page I get redirected to `http://localhost:4200/sign-in` and what I see is `page-not-found works!`.

How does that happen?

Comment: did you include `AuthRoutingModule` in your app.module `imports` section?

Answer (score 0):

From what you are getting it seems like the `AuthRoutingModule` is not imported into the context of your `AppModule`.

To resolve this, you need to import `AuthRoutingModule` into `AppModule` (ising the `imports:` parameter or into any of the `AppModule` imported modules.

The [angular router docs](https://angular.io/guide/router) are quite descriptive on how to configure this properly. I encourage you to follow the guide on this page, so you can refine what you already know.

Comment: `AuthRoutingModule` is included in the auth.module and that module is , in turn, included in core.module and the core is in app.module. I also tried including it in app.module but still no luck...

Comment: It's interesting that if I comment out the route with `path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent`, it works but the PageNotFound feature is indeed not there.

Comment: i think it might be the `pathMatch: 'full' ` from the child route, can you try removing it? ref: https://angular.io/api/router/Route#pathMatch